# Java ResultSet to JSP

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jsp

Can I transmit a ResultSet from a Servlet to a JSP file and using it in a c:forEach ?

At the moment I'm doing it like this:

```
<sql:query dataSource="${datasource}" var="result">SELECT * FROM events WHERE DATE >= CURDATE() ORDER BY Date</sql:query>
<c:forEach var="events" items="${result.rows}">
```

But I want to create the ResultSet with Java like this:

```
String sqlSelectEvents = "SELECT * FROM events";
pstmt = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(sqlSelectEvents);
ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
request.setAttribute("rs", rs);
```

And then in JSP view:

```
<c:forEach var="events" items="${rs.rows}">
```

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: It doesnt work :/ So it isn't possible to transmit a ResultSet to a JSP-File?

Comment: Doesnt work because.... ??? What is happening? Exception?

Comment: Actually nothing. It just doesn't work. The JSP-File doesnt throw an Exception, but it didnt iterate over the ResultSet-Items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a `list` and then transfer that list to `jstl`.

1. create a list say resultList
2. loop through resultset and add items to resultList
3. pass this list to jstl and using `<c:foreach>` loop it and get the
   elements

Answer (score 0):

You should set a Attribut in the .java file.

Code for Java part:

```
String sqlSelectEvents = "SELECT * FROM events";
pstmt = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(sqlSelectEvents);
ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
request.getSession().setAttribute("resultset", rs);
```

code for JSP part:

```
< c:forEach var="events" items="${resultset.rows}">
```